# How View Holder uses Singleton Design Pattern in Android?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-design-library

I know View Holder itself a design in android to not call findViewByID many times but I was reading articles regarding all the design used in android SDK code. At many places, this says View holder uses singleton design. Can Anyone help how view holder is using singleton design?

Comment: It's not using singleton design.

Comment: I am also in same impression ...its not using singleton because it needs to create multiple view holder for each cell

Answer (score 3):

No. View holder is not a singleton.

Your recycler view creates enough view-holders to fill the screen. On scrolling the recyclerview instead of creating a new view-holder, the recycler view recycles(Reuse the view that hides on scroll).

So the findviewbyId will not be called multiple times and only the value will be replaced in the view.

Comment: agree with your answer